# How do I find out what other groups have write permissions on a folder?

Tags: permissions

When I

```
ls -la
```

I get a folder that has a green background and blue text. My googling tells me this means its 'other writable'.

I think this means another group has write permission to this folder.

How do I find out what other groups have write permissions on that folder?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/690361/edit) and add the exact output you got from `ls -la` and also point out what directory you are talking about..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No particular group. That's just literally everyone else. If you don't want this, set it to 4 (read-only) or 0 (nothing).